# Sonar Oauth GitLab user authentication error

Tags: oauth, sonarqube, gitlab

I am using [Sonar Auth GitLab Plugin](https://gitlab.talanlabs.com/gabriel-allaigre/sonar-auth-gitlab-plugin/) to enable sonar user authentication and Single Sign-On via GitLab. I followed all the configuration details described, but when I log in I received the error "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed". I did not find any information regarding this and I successfully integrated other tools via GitLab OAuth. I am using SonarQube v5.6.3 and GitLab 8.9.1. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the error, the [latest release](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-auth-gitlab-plugin/releases) of Sonar Auth GitLab Plugin uses oauth scope = read_user and this is available from [GitLab v8.15](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens) on. So I installed the v1.0.0 of the plugin and everything worked. The ideal solution is to upgrade to v8.15 of GitLab.

Comment: Hi I cannot get this plug in to work. No matter what callback URL I provide in Gitlab, I get an error after clicking the Gitlab button. Currently Sonar is on a different server than Gitlab. https://gitlab.company.com Gitlab and https://gitlab.company.com/sonarqube. For the callback URL in Gitlab application, I tried both ```https://gitlab.company.com/sonarqube/oauth2/callback``` and ```https://gitlab.company.com/sonarqube/oauth2/callback/gitlab``` May I ask what value you used? Thanks.

Comment: The callback in GitLab is https://yoursonarserver/sonar/oauth2/callback/gitlab so the second should be ok if sonar is there. In the Sonar configuration you shoud put https://gitlab.company.com. What error do you receive? What version of GitLab and Sonar are you using?